# Exception when using ZipOutputStream and FileStream to zip files

Tags: c#, file, zip

I'm creating several backup files every couple of seconds in order to ensure the integrity of my system (requirement).

Because it is a lot of files, I'm using ZipOutputStream to zip files and save some space in disk. However, when the code reaches the File.OpenRead(filename), it throws the following exception:

The process cannot access the file 'inputfilefullnamehere' because it is being used by another process.

I thought it would be the exactly ZipOutputStream, so I tried to close it before opening the FileStream, but then I got another exception in StreamUtils.Copy() saying that there is no entry openned.

Is there something that I'm missing?

My code is:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];

ZipOutputStream s = new ZipOutputStream(File.Create(filename+ ".his"));

s.SetLevel(9); // 0 - store only to 9 - means best compression

ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(filename+ ".his");

s.PutNextEntry(entry);

using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(filename+ ".his"))
{
    StreamUtils.Copy(fs, s, buffer);
}

s.Close();

File.Delete(filename);
```

Comment: Shouldn't your zip file have a different name than the file you are zipping, like maybe `filename + ".his.zip"`?

Comment: 2nd line of your code, you open a file, but never close it. Then you try to open it again. Boom. I'd put together an answer, but trying to guess the intent of your error-prone filenames is tricky.

Comment: What is ZipOutputStream class? Cannot find it in .NET.

Comment: @spender I'm not the one who wrote this piece of code, I'm just the one who is in charge of solving the issue. I'm as confused as you. But I agree the problem relies on creating the file and not closing it, althought I don't really know when to do so if I'm also zipping it.

Comment: @mehrzad it's part of the ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib library https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib/wiki/Zip-Samples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass path of the source file(filename) to the `File.OpenRead` method, not the destination path. You get the access denied error since you are trying to read destination file which you have already opened to write to.

```
string sourceFileName = filename;
string destFileName = string.Format("{0}.his", filename);

using (ZipOutputStream s = new ZipOutputStream(File.Create(destFileName)) {
    s.SetLevel(9); // 0 - store only to 9 - means best compression    
    ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(filename);    
    s.PutNextEntry(entry);    
    using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(sourceFileName)) {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        StreamUtils.Copy(fs, s, buffer);
    }    
    s.Close();    
}
File.Delete(filename);
```